# Rails Paperclip nill the image field if user doesn't upload photo

Tags: mongoid, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, ruby-2.0

I am working on rails 4 ruby 2 project.
I had paperclip for upload files is working. But when the user doesn't upload any photo, paperclip remove the current uploaded photo and nill the field in the db.

How can I ignore the avatar field in case the user does not upload any photo and keep the previous uploaded one?

My model:
has_mongoid_attached_file :avatar,:styles => { :small => "300x300#"}

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 4 use strong parameters gem by default: https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

You can check if the avatar parameter is nil in the controller and don't permit it in this case. Something like this:

```
def user_params
  if params[:avatar]
    params.require(:user).permit(:avatar,:name,...)
  else
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,...)
  end
end
```